# How to update BIOS of dual boot Dell desktop with frozen GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside Windows 7 in my Dell desktop. Unfortunately, recently I am having a strange problem. I can not use down arrow key in the GRUB menu and unable to boot windows. By default it boots into Ubuntu. I wanted to update my Bios with the latest version which I have downloaded from Dell website but the latest BIOS update is provided as a .exe file. Can anybody please tell me how to solve this. I have tried to make the down arrow key to work in GRUB but in vain. Any help would be highly appreciated.

SanD

Comment: It's only in Grub that your key doesn't work?

Comment: Num-pad has an arrow-down-key too, does this one work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Num-pad arrow keys also don't work. Also it is only Grub where arrow key does not work.